# Radius of Curvature - Tracking detectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, particle-detectors

Suppose we want to build a tracking detector for acceleration experiments. In particular, the tracking detector is in a magnetic field with strength $B=4 T$ in order to measure the momenta of charged particles. We can assume that the magnetic field lines are parallel to the jet pipe, i.e., the magnetic field lines are perpendicular to the $xy$-plane.

Further, the particles come from the origin of the coordinate system and only move in the $xy$-plane.

(i) We are supposed to determine the curvature radii of muons with an impulse of $50$ GeV. 
(ii) We are also supposed to calculate the impulses at which the curvature radii are $R=55$ cm and $R=2$ cm (I guess we still consider muons).

Alright, I know of one formula which could be of use in this task: $p\cdot \cos\lambda = 0.3BR$, which I found in Mark Thomson's book "Modern Particle Physics", page 16.

> "Owing to the $\mathbf v \times \mathbf B$ Lorentz force, the trajectory of a charged particle in the axial magnetic field is a helix with a radius of curvature $R$ and a pitch angle $\lambda$, which for a singly charged particle ($|q|=e$) are related to its momentum by $p\cos\lambda = 0.3 BR$, where the momentum $p$ is given in GeV/c, $B$ is the magnetic flux density in tesla and $R$ is in metres." M. Thomson

Ähm, how do I obtain $\lambda$ in my case?  I don't understand yet what the pitch angle is.
Help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: this will help https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Map%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics%2C_Electricity%2C_and_Magnetism_(OpenStax)/11%3A_Magnetic_Forces_and_Fields/11.04%3A_Motion_of_a_Charged_Particle_in_a_Magnetic_Field#:~:targetText=A%20charged%20particle%20experiences%20a%20force%20when%20moving%20through%20a%20magnetic%20field.&targetText=If%20the%20field%20is%20in,path%20in%20a%20magnetic%20field.

Comment: @anna v. Ah, so we obtain the equation $r=\frac{mv}{qB}$. Since we know the impuls (i.e., $|\vec P|=\gamma|\beta|m$). Then we can solve for $v$ (which is contained in both $\beta$ and $\gamma$), and are finished then.